# IPhone: Custom Button - Why is title not showing?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

So I basically dragged a button from interface builder's library, turned it into a Custom button. Then I added one png for the "default state configuration" and another png for the "highlighted state configuration". Let's just assume these png's are a red box and a blue box.

Now, I'd like the Title to display for the button i.e., "Press Me" or something. But the Title doesn't show. Am I missing something?? (I also tried to have that text in different colors but no dice...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you setting imageForState or backgroundImageForState? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you setting imageForState or backGroundImageForState? :)

Comment: yes, although i'm doing this in interface builder in the button's inspector. so it's called 'image' and 'background'. i didn't see that background was for images too...